# following a hierarchy in beautiful soup

Tags: html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML file with following format:

```
<div class="entry"> 
<p>para1</p>
<p><a href="www.site.com">para2</a></p>
<p><div class="abc"> Ignore this part1</div> </p>
<p><script class="xyz">Ignore this part2 </script></p>
</div>
```

Suppose there is only one div tag with class value "entry". I want to print all text inside those p tags which are inside div tag with class value "entry" , except those p tags which are followed by div or script tag. So here I want to print "para1" and "para2" but not "Ignore this part1" and "Ignore this part2"
How do I achieve this using beautiful soup?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `lambda` expression to filter what you don't need.

Example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


example = """<div class="entry"> 
<p>para1</p>
<p><a href="www.site.com">para2</a></p>
<p><div class="abc"> Ignore this part1</div> </p>
<p><script class="xyz">Ignore this part2 </script></p>
<p>example para</p>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, 'html.parser')
entry = soup.find('div', class_="entry")
p = entry.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "p" and not (tag.find("div") 
or tag.find("script")))
for content in p:
    print (content.get_text(strip=True))
```

Outputs:

```
para1
para2
example para
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternativ solution with css selector

A simple solution could be the use of modern `css selectors`:

```
soup.select('div.entry p:not(:empty,:has(div,script))')
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example = '''<div class="entry"> 
<p>para1</p>
<p><a href="www.site.com">para2</a></p>
<p><div class="abc"> Ignore this part1</div> </p>
<p><script class="xyz">Ignore this part2 </script></p>
<p>example para</p>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, 'html.parser')

for e in soup.select('div.entry p:not(:empty,:has(div,script))'):
    print(e.text)
```

#### Output

```
para1
para2
example para
```